# The operator <= is undefined for the argument type int, Distance and more errors

Tags: java

I think I got the codes right on the Distance.java. Just stuck at trying to show the loop output from the Driver.java.

The problem is that it says "the operator <= is undefined for the argument type int, Distance" and "hours" is a duplicate local variable.

"The operator <= is undefined for the argument type int, Distance" is probably due to the fact that "distance.getDistance(distance);" being shown as a string. but how would I make it a double? And how would I solve the "hours" problem.

```
public class Distance {

    // creating private statement
    private double speed;
    private int hours;

    // creating a Distance method
    public Distance() {

        // creating getters and setters
    }

    public double getSpeed() {
        return speed;
    }

    public void setSpeed(double speed) {
        this.speed = speed;
    }

    public int getHours() {
        return hours;
    }

    public void setHours(int hours) {
        this.hours = hours;
    }

    // setting up distance equation
    public double getDistance(double distance) {
        return distance = hours * speed;
    }
}
```

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Driver {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        // setting up a scanner
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        // creating objects
        Distance speed = new Distance();
        Distance hours = new Distance();
        Distance distance = new Distance();

        distance.getDistance(distance);

        // input for vehicle speed and hour
        System.out.println("Please enter vehicle speed: ");
        scanner.nextDouble();
        speed.setSpeed(scanner.nextDouble());

        System.out.println("Please enther hours vehicle was in motion: ");
        scanner.nextInt();
        hours.setHours(scanner.nextInt());

        System.out.println("Hour\tDistance Travelled\n----\t----------");
        for (int hours = 1; hours <= distance; hours++) {

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Well, you defined two variables with the name `hours`:

- here: `Distance hours = new Distance();`
- and here: `for (int hours = 1; hours <= distancel; hours++)`

And about the `<=`: you are trying to compare complex objects, since `hours` (the first definition) and `distance` are instances of `Distance` class. Therefore, the two errors.

Answer (score 1):

The operator `<=` is meant to be used with the primitive types (e.g. int, long, double etc.) or their boxed types (e.g. Integer, Long, Double etc.), not for other types.

You do not need to create as many objects as for each input as long as the inputs are supposed to be for just one object. Also, the `getDistance` function needs to be changed to return the distance based on `speed` and `time` without requiring the distance to be passed to it as a parameter.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Distance {
    private double speed;
    private int hours;

    public double getSpeed() {
        return speed;
    }

    public void setSpeed(double speed) {
        this.speed = speed;
    }

    public int getHours() {
        return hours;
    }

    public void setHours(int hours) {
        this.hours = hours;
    }

    public double getDistance() {
        return hours * speed;
    }
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        // Creating an object of Distance
        Distance distance = new Distance();

        // Input for vehicle speed and hour
        System.out.print("Please enter vehicle speed: ");
        distance.setSpeed(scanner.nextDouble());

        System.out.print("Please enter hours vehicle was in motion: ");
        distance.setHours(scanner.nextInt());

        // Display the result
        System.out.printf("Hour: %d, Speed: %f, Distance Travelled: %f", distance.getHours(), distance.getSpeed(),
                distance.getDistance());
    }
}
```

**A sample run:**

```
Please enter vehicle speed: 50.5
Please enter hours vehicle was in motion: 5
Hour: 5, Speed: 50.500000, Distance Travelled: 252.500000
```

Comment: Thanks, but this isn't the answer I needed, hints would be nice. I'm trying to make a loops so basically if I input the hours and speed there would be a loop showing the amount ongoing with the hours and speed. For example if I were to input the hour of 1 and the speed of 30, it would show the loop for hour 2, 3 ,4 with the ongoing speed.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [JLS §15.20.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.20.1):

> The type of each of the operands of a numerical comparison operator must be a type that is convertible (§5.1.8) to a primitive numeric type, or a compile-time error occurs.

Your `distance` is a reference type variable, that cannot be an operand used with a `<=` numerical operator. Both of this operator's operands *must* be primitives, or anything that can be unboxed to the primitives.